# Why do I get this error when trying to read integers from a file and copy them into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file named "hours.txt" that has lines of integers that I would like to read and copy them into an array.

The integers are the number of hours worked by 8 employees in a week. So I created a two-dimensional array with the rows being the employees and the columns being the days of the week.

```
public static void read()
{

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("hours.txt"));
    int[][] hours = new int[8][7];


    for(int r=0; r<hours.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<hours[0].length; c++)
        {
            while(read.hasNextInt())
            {
                hours[r][c]= read.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

> EmployeeHours.java:16: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Why is that?

Comment: You are using eclipse ide right?

Comment: You need a `try-catch` block

Comment: Frankly, the reported error (depending on how much you understand of it) either 1) tells you exactly what the problem is, or 2) gives you great keywords to search for on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
   //block of code 
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
}
```

or

```
public static void read() throws FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: Well, when I do the second method, it says "cannot find symbol" for some reason.

Comment: I just copied what you wrote. But I guess there might be something else wrong with my code then

Comment: Use this import. import java.io.FileNotFoundException, you are using an IDE right?

Comment: Yes, I am. And that import worked actually. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Because `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception. You must either [`catch` **and handle it**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html), or `throws` it in the method declaration. And don't just swallow the exception; that's almost never the right way to "handle" them.

Lots more reading on exactly this topic can be found [in the official Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

Comment: Beat me to it by a couple seconds!

Comment: I'll read up on that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The exception `FileNotFoundException` must be declared as part of your method signature, to tell the Java compiler that your method can throw that particular exception. You must change your method definition to:

```
public static void read() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    ... code here ...
}
```

Comment: Or, you could also just `catch` and swallow the exception...

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: I never said one _should_; I only said one _can_. But could point anyway.